# MariaDB replication - enabling compression

Tags: replication, mariadb, compression

We've got a MariaDB database that's already being replicated and we wanted to turn on compression.  I found the slave_compressed_protocol variable and see that it has to be turned on both on the master and the replica (it's currently off on both).  My question is whether there is a specific sequence to this?  Slave first then master?  Also, I saw online that I need to stop and then start the slave after making the change, but do I need to do something similar on the master for it to take effect?  I want to do it safely so I don't mess up the contents of the replica DB.  Thanks.